# Excel conditional formatting based on cell and adjacent cell values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to format a cell in Excel based on the cell above it's value.
Basically I'm compiling a spreadsheet and I want the cell to be highlighted in light green if the value has gone down since the entry above and I want it to go red if it has increased.

I'm sure its fairly simple but I just cant get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: #1 result in google - #1 reason to block SO from future search results...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is to use Conditional Formatting with a formula.

For example, if the two cells are A1 and A2, with A2 being the cell you want to change color, then you would select A2 and choose Conditional Formatting from the Home ribbon. Then select New Rule and "Use a formula to determine which cells to format."

Then, in the formula bar that comes up enter `=A2>A1` and choose the red fill as the format you want to use.

This only works one cell at a time; can't select a range of cell and expect each cell format to based on it's own adjacent cell

Then create another rule for cell A2 using the formula `=A2<A1` and choose light green as the format.

[image]